# How to store objects max(date) and min(date) from mysql query

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, max, min

I'm semi-new from C# and i've never store objects from mysql query. I've declared 2 Datetimes variables:

```
DateTime date_min
DateTime date_max
```

I'd like to store max(date) and min(date) from below query

```
string query1 = "SELECT MIN(order_status.BEGIN_DATE) AS 'BEGIN DATE', MAX(order_status.END_DATE) AS 'END DATE' FROM project1.order_status INNER JOIN project1.orders ON orders.ID_ORDER = order_status.ID_ORDER WHERE orders.NUMBER_ORDER = 'TEST';";
```

like: `max(date) = MAX(order_status.END_DATE)`

```
min(date) = MIN(order_status.BEGIN_DATE)
```

which i want use in this loop:

```
    for (DateTime date = date_min; date <= date_max; date = date.AddDays(1))
    {             
        string query2 = "SELECT COUNT(leave.ID_PRACOWNIKA) AS 'NUMBER OF WORKERS ON LEAVE' FROM project1.leave WHERE DATE(leave.BEGIN_DATE) <= '"+date+"' AND DATE(leave.END_DATE) >= '"+date+"';";
        string query3 = "SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.END_DATE) - TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.BEGIN_DATE))), '%H:%i:%s') AS 'TIME OF ALL ORDERS IN DAY' FROM project1.order_status INNER JOIN project1.orders ON orders.ID_ORDER = order_status.ID_ORDER WHERE (DATE(order_status.BEGIN_DATE) = '"+date+"' AND DATE(order_status.END_DATE) = '"+date+"');";
        string query4 = "SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.END_DATE) - TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.BEGIN_DATE))), '%H:%i:%s') AS 'TIME OF ORDER IN DAY' FROM project1.order_status INNER JOIN project1.orders ON orders.ID_ORDER  = order_status.ID_ORDER WHERE (DATE(order_status.BEGIN_DATE) = '"+date+"' AND DATE(order_status.END_DATE) = '"+date+"') AND orders.NUMBER_ORDER = 'TEST';";
    }
```

Can someone please show what should kind of code line should I write? maybe cmd.Parameters is enough? THX for any help.

there is my code:

```
 public partial class GenerateChartsOfOrders : Form
    {
        DateTime date_min;
        DateTime date_max;
        public GenerateChartsOfOrders()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void loaddata2()
        {
string query1 = "SELECT MIN(order_status.BEGIN_DATE) AS 'BEGIN DATE', MAX(order_status.END_DATE) AS 'END DATE' FROM project1.order_status INNER JOIN project1.orders ON orders.ID_ORDER = order_status.ID_ORDER WHERE orders.NUMBER_ORDER = 'TEST';";

            for (DateTime date = date_min; date <= date_max; date = date.AddDays(1))
            {             
                string query2 = "SELECT COUNT(leave.ID_PRACOWNIKA) AS 'NUMBER OF WORKERS ON LEAVE' FROM project1.leave WHERE DATE(leave.BEGIN_DATE) <= '"+date+"' AND DATE(leave.END_DATE) >= '"+date+"';";
                string query3 = "SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.END_DATE) - TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.BEGIN_DATE))), '%H:%i:%s') AS 'TIME OF ALL ORDERS IN DAY' FROM project1.order_status INNER JOIN project1.orders ON orders.ID_ORDER = order_status.ID_ORDER WHERE (DATE(order_status.BEGIN_DATE) = '"+date+"' AND DATE(order_status.END_DATE) = '"+date+"');";
                string query4 = "SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.END_DATE) - TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.BEGIN_DATE))), '%H:%i:%s') AS 'TIME OF ORDER IN DAY' FROM project1.order_status INNER JOIN project1.orders ON orders.ID_ORDER  = order_status.ID_ORDER WHERE (DATE(order_status.BEGIN_DATE) = '"+date+"' AND DATE(order_status.END_DATE) = '"+date+"') AND orders.NUMBER_ORDER = 'TEST';";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExecuteReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) to retrieve the value as below,

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
using(var command = new MySqlCommand(query1, con))
{
    using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
       while (reader.Read())
       {
        date_min = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]);
        date_max = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[1]);
       }
    }
}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: okey, but this which you've written should i add in my code or after my code?